# How to snmpset counter32 OIDs using netsnmp

Tags: snmp

I'm trying to use snmpset from netsnmp to set an OID value of type Counter32, but I can't figure out which datatype to specify?

Looking at ./snmpset -h I see the following:

```
  TYPE: one of i, u, t, a, o, s, x, d, b, n
        i: INTEGER, u: unsigned INTEGER, t: TIMETICKS, a: IPADDRESS
        o: OBJID, s: STRING, x: HEX STRING, d: DECIMAL STRING, b: BITS
        U: unsigned int64, I: signed int64, F: float, D: double
```

None of which are counter, I've tried integer and unsigned int without success:

```
./snmpset -v2c -cprivate 135.115.155.132 1.3.6.1.2.1.67.1.1.1.1.5.0 u 321
Bad variable type (Type of attribute is Counter32, not Unsigned32)
```

Thoughts?

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this man page](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/cgi-systems/man.cgi?section=1M&topic=snmpset) you can use c :

```
./snmpset -v2c -cprivate 135.115.155.132 1.3.6.1.2.1.67.1.1.1.1.5.0 c 321
```

I'am not able to try at the moment. I'am not sure it's for Net-SNMP [this tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3317126&group_id=12694&atid=362694) seems to show that it's a feature requested.

Comment: snmpset command does not work for Counter types, based on this: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2578#section-7.1.6

I tested this in Ubuntu 16.04 with snmpd version 5.8, this error occurred:


"Bad object type: c"

Comment: It was tested on 2011 ... 10 years ago on a tool I gace the man, but seem to no longer exist !